# ElasticSearch query/search/match

Tags: elasticsearch

I have inserted 3 records in my ElasticSearch index as follows:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/geoindex_test/STREET?pretty=1'  -d '
{ "cityNames" : [ { "language" : "ENG",
    "name" : "w bridgewater",
    "raw_name" : "W BRIDGEWATER"
  },
  { "language" : "ENG",
    "name" : "west bridgewater",
    "raw_name" : "West Bridgewater"
  }
],
"id" : 1,
  "streetNames" : [ { "language" : "ENG",
    "name" : "cram rd",
    "raw_name" : "Cram Rd"
  } ]
}'

curl -XPOST 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/geoindex_test/STREET?pretty=1'  -d '
{ "cityNames" : [ { "language" : "ENG",
    "name" : "bridgewater corners",
    "raw_name" : "BRIDGEWATER CORNERS"
  },
  { "language" : "ENG",
    "name" : "bridgewater center",
    "raw_name" : "Bridgewater Center"
  }
],
"id" : 2,
"streetNames" : [ { "language" : "ENG",
    "name" : "valley view rd",
    "raw_name" : "Valley View Rd"
  } ]
}'

curl -XPOST 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/geoindex_test/STREET?pretty=1'  -d '
{ "cityNames" : [ { "language" : "ENG",
    "name" : "bridgewater",
    "raw_name" : "Bridgewater"
  },
  { "language" : "ENG",
    "name" : "windsor",
    "raw_name" : "Windsor"
  }
],
"id" : 3,
"streetNames" : [ { "language" : "ENG",
    "name" : "valley view rd",
    "raw_name" : "Valley View Rd"
  } ]
}'
```

And I perform a search as follows:

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/geoindex_test/STREET/_search?pretty=1'  -d '
{
"query" : {
    "match" : { "cityNames.name" : "bridgewater" }
}
}'
```

I thought ElasticSearch would return the third record (id == 3) as the best match (record 3 is the only exact match to "bridgewater"), but instead it returns the record for id 1 (w bridgewater) as the best match.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can see a detailed explanation of why if you enable the explain output in your request. Just add the `explain=true` request parameter to the url. I would be glad to help you with that if you can add the output to your answer.

Comment: @javanna - Thanks your reply.  The output from explain=true exceeds the number of characters allowed by stackoverflow.  Sorry, I cannot provide the info.

Comment: Maybe you can just post the relevant part or use a third-party service like pastebin or a github gist.

Comment: @javanna - I have never used pastebin before.  Hopefully you can access my post:  http://pastebin.com/bfZQ9Uny

Comment: The answer you got is perfectly fine. As you can see you have tf (term frequency) 2 for your first two documents, for the very same reason explained in the answer. The fieldNorm for the third document is higher, and that's the factor that tells it's a perfect match, but since the term frequency is only one the other documents are more relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine this is happening because you are using inner objects which basically collapse the objects under it, into one for search purposes. So when you're querying the search field for Object 1, for example, you're querying against ["w bridgewater", "west bridgewater"] and not discrete fields as you may imagine.

Since 'bridgewater' appears twice in object 1 and 2 (two name fields) vs once in object 3, those items rank higher in the search. Object 1 is ultimately picked, because the fields that 'bridgewater' appears in are shorter strings than in Object 2 ("w bridgewater" vs "bridgewater corners").

Instead of using inner objects like you're doing, use nested objects instead http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/nested-type/. setting the score mode to "max" will then make things match in a more intuitive manner for you.

Comment: You know what? I like the way you edited your answer, makes sense! Even though seeing the output of the explain always helps!